# Bind dynamic checkbox list to model is not working in razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

```html
<div class="card shadow-card">
    <div class="card-body form-check-inline">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.fruites.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div class="form-check mr-3">
                <input type="checkbox" value="@Model.fruites[i].Id" name="Model.AssignedFruite" />
                <label>@Model.fruites[i].Name</label>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Page Model

```cs
[BindProperty]
public List<string> AssignedFruite { get; set; }
```

Comment: Have you added a `form` tag around your checkboxes?

Answer (score 2):

To bind a `List<String>` to check boxes, ensure that the `name` attribute on every checkbox is identical and matches the name of  the property you are binding to. Then assign the string for each item to the `value` attribute:

```
<div class="card shadow-card">
    <div class="card-body form-check-inline">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.fruites.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div class="form-check mr-3">
                <input type="checkbox" value="@Model.fruites[i].Name" name="AssignedFruite" />
                <label>@Model.fruites[i].Name</label>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

If you actually wanted to collect the `Id` of each item rather than its `Name`, bind to a `List<int>` instead (assuming that the Id is an `int`, not a `GUID`).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to bind a list with a CheckBox. You should either bind a list with a DropDownList or a bool with a CheckBox.
Otherwise, if you must bind a list with a CheckBox list you can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315319/razor-page-core-bind-dynamic-checkbox-list-to-model)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. but the real issue was checkbox section is not in the form.